# ifElse statement with state?

Tags: javascript, sockets, functional-programming, ramda.js

### Background

I am making an app that receives messages from several devices. Upon receiving a messages an event is fired with the given message:

```
on( "data", message => {
    //doSomething
} );
```

### Challenge

This function receives two types of messages: A and B:

- message A has the id of the device
- message B has some info about a deivce

My first approach to dealing with this was the following:

```
const { ifElse } = require("ramda");

const evalData = ifElse(
    isTypeA,        // Returns true if type A, false otherwise
    evalTypeA,      // Returns device Id
    evalTypeB       // Processes data in message and returns bytes read
);

on( "data", evalData );
```

### Problem

The problem here is that messages of type B don't have the Id of the device they belong to. So to properly process the message I need the deviceId that `evalTypeA` returned in a previous message.

My idea to tackle this was to pass the Id to `evalTypeB`:

```
const evalData = messages => {
    let id = undefined;
    id = ifElse(
        isTypeA,        // Returns true if type A, false otherwise
        evalTypeA,      // Returns device Id
        evalTypeB( id )       // Processes data in message and returns bytes read
    )( message );
}
```

The problem here is that this wouldn't work! `evalTypeB` also returns a number and then I would have no idea if what the `ifElse` expression is given me is a number of bytes read or an Id!

### Question

How would you solve this without mutation and side effects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, a pure function that is called repeated times as the callback for `on('data', callback)` can not keep track of state from previous calls.

With that in mind, there are a couple of options to consider to help try to minimise or localise the side-effects:

1. Close over the state, keeping the logic free of side-effects:

```js
const processMsg = ifElse(isTypeA, evalTypeA, evalTypeB)

const handler = initialState => {
  let state = initialState
  return msg => {
      state = processMsg(state, msg)
  }
}

on('data', handler(42))
```

2. Recursively attach a new handler that will only be called once for each message at the end of each call, limiting the effects to the handler registration (this assumes something like `once` is supported by the event emitter):

```js
const processMsg = ifElse(isTypeA, evalTypeA, evalTypeB)

const handler = state => msg =>
  once('data', handler(processMsg(state, msg)))

once('data', handler(42))
```

Comment: Solution 2 is so obvious! How didn't I think about it? Thanks !